# AngularJS:ng-show behaving different

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am trying out Angular JS applications and I think my ng-show is behaving wierdly.

I have listed the working version and the not working version of the code (as an image) below.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ2hy.png)

As per the documentation and examples online, I expect "***ng-show=displayList***", but it is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it like

```
$scope.displayList = false;
```

make it boolean rather than a string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$scope.displayList = "false"
```

give:

```
$scope.displayList = false
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-show required Boolean so do as change code as below..

```
$scope.displayList = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean instead of string false instead of "false"